# Error while using pyAudio to play a sound in a specific mic (VB virtual cable)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im creating a text-to-speech (is more like voice-to-text-to-speech lmao), like u say something then it traduce it in text and finally a bot says the traduction. Now im trying to play a sound in a virtual microphone (not just a speaker).
So here is the error I got, I tried using multiple channels btw (1, 2, 6, 8, etc..) :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\voicevoxRealtime\main.py", line 150, in on_submit
    main(lang, speaker, mic, mic_input)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\voicevoxRealtime\main.py", line 139, in main
    audio_binary = asyncio.run(synthesize_speech(translated_text, speaker, mic))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\voicevoxRealtime\main.py", line 106, in synthesize_speech
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\voicevoxRealtime\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaudio\__init__.py", line 639, in open
    stream = PyAudio.Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rayan\PycharmProjects\voicevoxRealtime\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaudio\__init__.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

My code:

```
async def synthesize_speech(text, speaker, mic):
async with Client() as client:
    audio_query = await client.create_audio_query(text, speaker=speaker)
    audio_binary = await audio_query.synthesis(speaker=speaker)

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    # Play the audio in the virtual mic
    if mic:

        def find_virtual_cable_device_index():
            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            device_index = None
            for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
                device_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
                if "CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" in device_info["name"]:
                    device_index = i
                    break
            p.terminate()
            return device_index

        # Find the VB-Audio Virtual Cable device index
        virtual_cable_device_index = find_virtual_cable_device_index()
        if virtual_cable_device_index is None:
            print("VB-Audio Virtual Cable not found")
        else:
            print(f"VB-Audio Virtual Cable found at index {virtual_cable_device_index}")

        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=8,
                        rate=24000,
                        output=True,
                        output_device_index=int(virtual_cable_device_index))

        stream.write(audio_binary)
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

        p.terminate()
    # Else : just play the audio in the default speaker
    else:
        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=1,
                        rate=24000,
                        output=True)

        stream.write(audio_binary)
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

        p.terminate()

    return audio_binary
```

Here is some info that can be helpful ig ?

got this from pyAudio :

```
{'index': 9, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)', 'hostApi': 1, 'maxInputChannels': 8, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.12, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.24, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.0, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

Python 3.11, Windows x64
(Btw excuse me for my bad english I mostly talk french)

**UPDATE:**
So i fixed the errors in the terminal, but actually it doesnt play the audio in the microphone.
new code:

```
async def synthesize_speech(text, speaker, mic):
    try:
        async with Client() as client:
            audio_query = await 
            client.create_audio_query(text,speaker=speaker)
            audio_binary = await audio_query.synthesis(speaker=speaker)
    except Exception:
        print("Error while connecting with client!")

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    if mic:

        def find_virtual_cable_device_info():
            device_info = None
            for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
                current_device_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
                if "CABLE Output" in current_device_info["name"]:
                    device_info = current_device_info
                    print(f'{device_info["name"]} found at index {device_info["index"]}')
                    break
            return device_info

        # Find the VB-Audio Virtual Cable device information
        virtual_cable_device_info = find_virtual_cable_device_info()
        if virtual_cable_device_info is None:
            print("VB-Audio Virtual Cable not found")

        virtual_cable_device_index = virtual_cable_device_info["index"]
        channels = virtual_cable_device_info["maxOutputChannels"]

        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=channels,
                        rate=44100,
                        output=True,
                        output_device_index=int(virtual_cable_device_index))
```